# How to create a formula that will repeat a range by splitting one column and joining with the other column?

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, first-normal-form

I have 2 columns, first name and surname. I want to split a cell that contains multiple values and then combine it with the cell on the right. I have no idea how to do this using a formula, please help.

Before:

| First Name | Surname |
| --- | --- |
| John,Jane,Mary | Fish |
| Albert,Steven,Alice | Smith |

Expected Result:

| First Name | Surname |
| --- | --- |
| John | Fish |
| Jane | Fish |
| Mary | Fish |
| Albert | Smith |
| Steven | Smith |
| Alice | Smith |

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(A1:A, ","))="",,SPLIT(A1:A, ",")&"​"&B1:B)), "​"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by looping over the range twice. First, loop over the range with `REDUCE`. Then `SPLIT` each of  column A, then loop over each split of Column A and create a dynamic array using array literals: `{}`

```
=REDUCE(
  A1:B1,
  A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)), 
  LAMBDA(a,c, 
    {
      a;
      REDUCE(
        "",
        SPLIT(c,","),
        LAMBDA(
          a_,
          c_,
          IF(
            a_="",
            {c_,OFFSET(c,0,1)},
            {a_;{c_,OFFSET(c,0,1)}}
          )
        )
      )
    }
  )
)
```

| First Name | Surname |
| --- | --- |
| John | Fish |
| Jane | Fish |
| Mary | Fish |
| Albert | Smith |
| Steven | Smith |
| Alice | Smith |