# How to create new rows of data based on a single cell within an arrayforumla-wrapped-query call in google sheets?s?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, first-normal-form

I currently have a dataset that is formatted:

| Company | Clients | Date | Type | Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| comp1 | client1, client2, client3 | 01/02/22 | visa | $1500 |
| comp2 | client1 |  | amex | $600 |
| comp3 | client3, client4, client5, client1 | 02/23/22 | check | $4000 |
| comp4 | client6, client7, client8 |  | check | $1800 |

And I would like to end up with a dataset formatted for each client transaction:

| Client | Date | Type | Amt | Company | Expense type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client1 | 01/02/22 | visa | $500 | comp1 | Company |
| client2 | 01/02/22 | visa | $500 | comp1 | Company |
| client3 | 01/02/22 | visa | $500 | comp1 | Company |
| client1 |  | amex | $600 | comp2 | Company |
| client3 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3 | Company |
| client4 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3 | Company |
| client5 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3 | Company |
| client1 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3 | Company |
| client6 |  | check | $600 | comp4 | Company |
| client7 |  | check | $600 | comp4 | Company |
| client8 |  | check | $600 | comp4 | Company |

Thanks to user [player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) for pointing me in the right direction with:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B1:B, ","))="",,
 SPLIT(B1:B, ", ", )&"​"&C1:C&"​"&D1:D&"​"&E1:E/LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(1/(1/(SPLIT(B1:B, ",")<>"")))),,9^9)), " ", ))&"​"&A1:A)), "​"), 
 "where Col3 is not null format Col2'mm/dd/yy', Col4'$0'", ))
```

This comes very close to accomplishing what I'm trying to do, but shifts cells when there are missing values so the end result looks like:

| Client | Date | Type | Amt | Company | Expense type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client1 | 01/02/22 | visa | $500 | comp1 |  |
| client2 | 01/02/22 | visa | $500 | comp1 |  |
| client3 | 01/02/22 | visa | $500 | comp1 |  |
| client1 | amex | $600 | comp2 |  |  |
| client3 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3 |  |
| client4 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3 |  |
| client5 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3 |  |
| client1 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3 |  |
| client6 | check | $600 | comp4 |  |  |
| client7 | check | $600 | comp4 |  |  |
| client8 | check | $600 | comp4 |  |  |

To work around this I added an if statement for each column call that checks if its empty and fills in with a space if it is empty. This gets things in the correct order, but there may be a more efficient way?
The last thing to do is populate the final column with the broad category of "company", basically populate all cells in col 6 to equal the header from col 1 in the original table. This new formula looks like this:

```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))=""
    ,,SPLIT(B2:B, ",",)&"​"&IF(C2:C<>"",C2:C," ")&"​
    "&IF(!D2:D<>"",!D2:D," ")&"​  
    "&IF(!E2:E<>"",!E2:E/LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
    IFERROR(1/(1/(SPLIT(!B2:B,",")<>"")))),,9^9))," ",))," ")&"​   
    "&IF(!A2:A<>"",!A2:A," ")&"
    "&!A1)), "​"),
    "Where Col5 is not null format Col2'mm/dd/yy', Col5'$0'", 0))
```

This generates the final field of "Company" but puts it appended to the previous column. I believe this is happening because `ARRAYFORMULA` wants to be working with ranges of the same size and so interprets this as a string concatenation since it can't operate on the range? If anyone has other thoughts as to why please let me know!

| Client | Date | Type | Amt | Company | Expense type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client1 | 01/02/22 | visa | $500 | comp1Company |  |
| client2 | 01/02/22 | visa | $500 | comp1Company |  |
| client3 | 01/02/22 | visa | $500 | comp1Company |  |
| client1 |  | amex | $600 | comp2Company |  |
| client3 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3Company |  |
| client4 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3Company |  |
| client5 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3Company |  |
| client1 | 02/23/22 | check | $1000 | comp3Company |  |
| client6 |  | check | $600 | comp4Company |  |
| client7 |  | check | $600 | comp4Company |  |
| client8 |  | check | $600 | comp4Company |  |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a formula that will repeat a range by splitting one column and joining with the other column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74065157/how-to-create-a-formula-that-will-repeat-a-range-by-splitting-one-column-and-joi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B1:B, ","))="",,
 SPLIT(B1:B, ", ", )&"​"&C1:C&"​"&D1:D&"​"&E1:E/LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(1/(1/(SPLIT(B1:B, ",")<>"")))),,9^9)), " ", ))&"​"&A1:A)), "​"), 
 "where Col3 is not null format Col2'mm/dd/yy', Col4'$0'", ))
```

[image]

Comment: That almost works! Here is a cleaned up version of the data I'm working with. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nngf-r115CTt---BHI80CkpxlnnL_NFrBHnUOnjOCGo/edit#gid=77843647) data types for columns I'm not using. Its not uniform, there are a lot of null values. You can see in the your edited Query in the "Reporting formatted" tab. I believe I understand your formula, and think its "shifting" data 1 cell to the left where there are null values in the initial IF statement that compiles all of the cells for the Query range. Is there a way to make this IF statement keep null values?

Comment: Edited the original dataset to include null values and has the same effect, cells shifted

Answer (score 0):

Best I could come up with was to leave that column out of the QUERY and just have it populate IF the client is not empty, worked well enough. Still curious if there's a simple way to create a repeating array in a query

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).